# Live chat in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to create a live chat and Video Conference and Video messages in silverlight 4.0. I have tried many code but they are not working for me. I am new in this type of code.how can I achieve this all?

Comment: I have gone through the following links but it only capture only video and i want live chat:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7123/Capture-Live-Video-from-various-Video-Devices  and http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/2ee4d1ad-afe5-4394-b61d-59755fdf7734

Answer (score 0):

You can use WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) for this. It allows you to build a "duplex"-communication between server and (Silverlight) client(s).
Google for wcf chat duplex silverlight - there are many examples out there.

The other way is to use sockets - it's faster but you have to build it on your own. WCF has many build in standards, so it can save you a lot of work.